# how to avoid type field in request and response @jsoninfotype

Tags: json, jackson

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,visible = false, property = "type")
    public interface ItemId {

        String getItemValue();

        String getItemType();

    }

  //implemented class   
    public class ItemIdImpl implements ItemId{
    //class properties
    private final String itemvalue;
        private final String itemtype;

        //getters & setters below 

    }

    This interface is passed into method as post body 

    post body format :
```

[
{"itemvalue":"inpound","itemtype":"fashion","type":"com.demo.sand.model.ItemIdImpl"},
{"itemvalue":"inpound","itemtype":"fashion","type":"com.demo.sand.model.ItemIdImpl"}
]

```
//request passed into method body
    public ItemStatus getItems(@RequestBody List<ItemId> items)

    i am getting proper response.

    But i want to avoid sending the type in the request body ....
    like below :
//request body to be passed

    [
    {"itemvalue":"inpound","itemtype":"fashion"}, 
    {"itemvalue":"inpound","itemtype":"fashion"}   
    ]

    its not working in this way .what annotations i can use to avoid sending 
    type in request body?
```

Comment: after doing a look around i tried this @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,visible = false,defaultImpl = ItemIdImpl.class)  100 % worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have simple interface/implementation relationship, you should not use `@JsonTypeInfo`, as that is only needed for polymorphic usage (multiple possible implementations).

Instead you can either use annotations to specify implementation (interface/abstract class with `@JsonDeserialize(as=Impl.class)`), or register mapping for abstract type (see `SimpleModule` method `addAbstractTypeMapping()`).

Comment: only @JsonDeserialize(as=Impl.class)) is needed or along with that @Jsonserialize(as=Impl.class))

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: either use `@JsonTypeInfo` (for polymorphic), or, if not, either annotation(s) (`@JsonDeserialize`) OR register subtype mapping. Not all, or more than one. One of them, depending on exact need and preferences.